Who is Gall in Italo Svevo's "Senilità"?
I'm reading Italo Svevo's novel Senilità, translated into English as As a Man Grows Older or Emilio's Carnival. In the third chapter, someone called Gall is mentioned (emphasis mine):

Ella portava la testina eternamente inclinata sulla spalla destra. – Segno di vanità, secondo il Gall – osservava Emilio, e con la serietà di uno scienziato che fa degli esperimenti, aggiungeva: – Chissà che le osservazioni del Gall non sieno meno errate di quanto generalmente si creda?

This is rendered this way in Beryl de Zoete's translation (emphasis is always mine):

She had a way of carrying her head continually bent towards her left shoulder. 'A sign of vanity, according to Gall,' Emilio remarked, and with the gravity of a man of science engaged on an experiment, he added: Who knows whether Gall's observations were not much less inaccurate than is generally supposed?'

My question is: who is this Gall? He is not a character in the novel and is not mentioned anywhere else. Could it be a famous person in Trieste at the end of the 19th century?

Franz Joseph Gall was a nineteenth century professor of physiology, who is particularly noted for his contributions to founding the pseudo-science of phrenology. From the wikipedia article:

Gall believed that the bumps and uneven geography of the human skull
were caused by pressure exerted from the brain underneath. He divided
the brain into sections that corresponded to certain behaviors and
traits that he called fundamental faculties... Based on the surface of a person's skull, Gall could make
assumptions about that person's fundamental faculties and therefore
their character.

In the text Emilio makes an assertion similar to Gall's philosophy, that bending one's neck in a certain way indicates vanity.
